# Align two characters in Word vertically, tricky

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to align text in the following picture vertically, so that all characters have the same baseline (save for the indices). Preferably via VBA. Right now, "–1" is lower than "2", I'd like them to be on the same level.

What you see in the picture is an equation followed by a textbox aligned as "In Line With Text" containing a table with an equation inside one of its cells. The textbox is lowered via setting the `Selection.Font.Position` property to negative half of the textbox's height. That makes the middle of the textbox land at the baseline of the equation on the left. The baseline of "–1" however is not in the middle of the textbox.

I can't find the VBA properties that'd give me positions of characters. `Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)` isn't helpful.

[image: "2" isn't aligned with "–1"]

EDIT: I provide a sample document here: https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/2181938/test.docx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you be more specific? I have read the linked page a few times, what am I missing?

Comment: While you are using vba for some reason to approach this, it is not a programming question but rather a question about how Word itself works. The characters on the right appear to be in a table which means each cell has paragraph formatting including likely space-before/space-after formatting. The table may be in a text box which may itself be aligned. You could try linking a page that has the problem.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: The reason I want to use VBA is twofold: I want it done automatically for every diagram similar to the one I linked AND I want it done precisely, so there's calculations involved and only VBA can give me the information I need. I agree there's many properties that can be used to align these characters but I need to know the amount by which to change them. Therefore I need to obtain the position of the characters on the page.

Comment: I have prepared a sample document, so you can download it. The link is in the question.

Comment: Extend the table to the left so that the formula is in the middle row of a column of the table. Make the borders of that column invisible.